# SElinux package removes grub-efi

Tags: linux-mint, uefi, selinux

ON my linux mint 19.2 machine, I am trying to set up Selinux. But when i install selinux package, it removes grub-efi. When I try to reinstall grub-efi, it removes selinux

Does this mean selinux is not compatible with computers that boot in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  These technologies are unrelated and shouldn't logically interact.  There is a dependency in the package for selinux on grub-pc which is incompatible with grub-efi.  This is probably because enabling selinux requires adding it to the kernel options in the grub config and the package maintainer just added grub-pc to get that dependency.  It is [Ubuntu bug 1047099](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/selinux/+bug/1047099)

Comment: Luckily my PC still boots without grub-efi installed though I did disable secure boot. Can't get Linux mint to boot without selinux=0 anyhow